# Updating threejs from r99 to r128

Tags: three.js

I am using threejs version r99 for my project. I mostly rely on plyloader for rendering my 3d models. I was wondering if I can expect to see significant performance improvements if I were to update to the latest version? If someone can sum up the most notable changes made to threejs since r99 in terms of loading 3d models using plyloader, object picking using ray casting, and so on. Please let me know if it's worth updating the code to use the latest version of threejs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if I can expect to see significant performance improvements if I were to update to the latest version

That depends on the use case. There is no general performance improvement for all applications. However, certain applications can gain noticeable performance and rendering quality improvements especially on specific browsers and mobile devices.

- VAO support was added with `r118` which is a recommended approach for speed up WebGL state configuration.
- Releases like `r127` and `r119` noticeably improved the performance of the renderer when picking the correct shader program.
- `r126` fixed a long-standing rendering issue on Adreno GPUs (used in certain mobile devices).

These are just a small subset of the changes of the past 29 releases. So yes, it's definitely worth upgrading the engine.